# Ruby mongo command is retried indefinitely when erroring

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Using the `mongo Ruby driver I am trying to connect to a MongoDB Replica Set:

```rb
def get_mongo_client
  puts "Before"
  Mongo::Client.new(
    "mongodb://foo:bar@0.example.com,1.example.com/admin?replicaSet=rs0",
    connect: :replica_set
  ).use("mydb")
  puts "After"
end
```

When running the code in my irb I get this error:

```
irb(main):001:0> get_mongo_client
Before
W, [2023-10-02T09:26:53.237262 #109]  WARN -- : MONGODB | Failed to handshake with 0.example.com:27017: Mongo::Error::SocketError: EOFError: end of file reached (for 000.000.00.000:27017 (no TLS)):
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/socket.rb:341:in `rescue in handle_errors'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/socket.rb:335:in `handle_errors'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/socket.rb:127:in `read'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:205:in `deserialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/server/monitor/connection.rb:212:in `handshake!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/server/monitor/connection.rb:163:in `connect!'
W, [2023-10-02T09:26:53.238131 #109]  WARN -- : MONGODB | Failed to handshake with 1.example.com:27017: Mongo::Error::SocketError: EOFError: end of file reached (for 111.11.111.11:27017 (no TLS)):
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/socket.rb:341:in `rescue in handle_errors'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/socket.rb:335:in `handle_errors'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/socket.rb:127:in `read'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:205:in `deserialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/server/monitor/connection.rb:212:in `handshake!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/server/monitor/connection.rb:163:in `connect!'
After
=> nil
```

The fact that the error occurs is fine. It just means something is wrong with the database.

However, it seems the command is retried indefinitely. But not by the code itself. Because my `puts` statements are not invoked again. The terminal outputs this indefinitely:

```
irb(main):002:0> W, [2023-10-02T09:33:08.816808 #60]  WARN -- : MONGODB | Failed to handshake with 0.example.com:27017: Mongo::Error::SocketError: EOFError: end of file reached (for 111.111.11.111:27017 (no TLS)):
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/socket.rb:341:in `rescue in handle_errors'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/socket.rb:335:in `handle_errors'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/socket.rb:127:in `read'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:205:in `deserialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/server/monitor/connection.rb:212:in `handshake!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/server/monitor/connection.rb:163:in `connect!'
W, [2023-10-02T09:33:08.820731 #60]  WARN -- : MONGODB | Failed to handshake with 1.example.com:27017: Mongo::Error::SocketError: EOFError: end of file reached (for 000.00.000.00:27017 (no TLS)):
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/socket.rb:341:in `rescue in handle_errors'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/socket.rb:335:in `handle_errors'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/socket.rb:127:in `read'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/protocol/message.rb:205:in `deserialize'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/server/monitor/connection.rb:212:in `handshake!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mongo-2.12.1/lib/mongo/server/monitor/connection.rb:163:in `connect!'
```

How is this happening and how can I avoid this?

Comment: mongo allows retry operations: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/retryable-writes/ and https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/retryable-reads/

Comment: I have tried passing `retry_reads: false` and `retry_writes: false` as arguments, but they don't make a difference. Also, remember that that code finishes without pausing for retries. The retries are happening after the code has run, but are definitely triggered by the code.

Comment: IIRC there's an internal thread to monitor the database server for topology changes. Not sure if you can deactivate it upon initial connection failure.

Comment: @Stefan that is true, `server/monitor/` logic is internal background process that is responsible for pinging server and getting his state. As I know, it's impossible to stop it just because if the server become alive at some point, the driver should notice it

Comment: The ruby mongo driver implements an internal connection pool which is monitored and threaded. It will reconnect in the background by itself. You cannot disable it, it's how the driver works.

Comment: Also, it is not possible to have a replica set with two members, the minimum number is 3 (one can be an arbiter, which is an election-voting member that stores no data, but should be on a 3rd system).  Finally, if the mongo servers are configured to require TLS, then you must use TLS to connect or all connections will fail.  You would do this by adding "ssl: true" to connection options.  Further options may be needed if the mongo servers use self-signed certificates.